# 2D Animation keyframe issue

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, layers, 2d

I've created a small animation and started with a sketch, that part is working as it should. 
Now I tried to color in my project , only did one image thus far.

The problem is that the colored image is showing through all the keyframes and this is not what I want.

Does anyone know how I can fix that?

In the dope sheet those specific layers (shadow, color, highlights, ink) are only active on 1 keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured it out and will post the answer just in case a new 2D animator runs into the same issue.

The problem I had is solved with setting keyframes for the new layers (ink, color, shadows, highlights, etc..) on another frame in the dopesheet.
Because I had those layers only active on 1 frame in the dopesheet the image showed through the whole animation.